# Script Failing to Finish - Protected Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using a timed trigger with this script to add new columns daily to a school-wide tracking sheet. Recently, I've been getting notifications that the script is failing on only one of the sheets -- the second sheet in.

This is the error message I'm getting: "Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit."

I'm confused because the sheet that is failing isn't the one that is protected. The first sheet I have is protected (always has been and it's worked fine), but I have the code set to only run on the 2nd sheet onwards (see code below). It's the 2nd sheet that is failing to add the new columns. All other sheets work fine. There is nothing protected on the 2nd sheet.

This issue only started happening recently. It worked fine for over a year. Hoping someone can take a look and see where I'm going wrong. Can add more context if needed!

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

function doToEachSheet() {
  for (let i = 2; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    
    let x = ss.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]);
    
//  +-----------------+
//  | loop through -> |
//  +-----------------+

    x.insertColumnsBefore(4, 2);

    x.getRange('D2').setValue('=F2+1');
    let nDate = x.getRange('D2').getValue();

    let values = [ [ nDate, null ],[ "Left", "Returned" ] ];
    x.getRange('D2:E3').setValues(values);
    
    let rng = x.getRange('D2:E184');
    rng.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK );
    rng.setBorder(null, null, null, null, null, true, '#818181', null );
    rng.setBorder(null, null, null, null, true, null, '#d8d4d4', null );

      for ( let j = 3; j < 184; j+=5 ) {
      let r = "D" + [j] + ":E" + [j];
      x.getRange(r).setBorder( null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK );
    };

//  +----------+
//  | end loop |
//  +----------+

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two issues are likely unrelated.

### It's Behaving as Instructed

The reason the script is skipping your second sheet is that you are explicitly skipping it in this line of code:

```
  for (let i = 2; i < sheets.length; i++) {
```

`sheets[2]` references the 3rd index position in the array `sheets` rather than the 2nd, because array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

To start with the 2nd, change the code to

```
  for (let i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
```

### [Optionally] Add Multiple Exclusions

You could leave the code as `i = 0` and check for exclusions as part of the loop keying of the sheet index number or name. This would allow easily adding more than one exception in different positions.

Excluding by sheet name is my preference, as I prefer not to worry about the sheet order which may be impacted when adding and removing sheets.

```
# By Sheet Name
if ( [ "summary", "Charts" ].indexOf(x.getSheetName()) === -1) { }

# By Index
if ( [ 0, 1 ].indexOf(i) === -1) { }
```

### Example Script

The example below uses an array of sheet names, `skiplist`, to exclude sheets, and wraps the loop's code with an `if` condition that the current sheet name NOT match any names in `skiplist`:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const skiplist = [ "summary", "Charts" ];

function doToEachSheet() {
 
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    
    let x = ss.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]);    

    if (skiplist.indexOf(x.getSheetName() === -1)) {

      x.insertColumnsBefore(4, 2);
      x.getRange('D2').setValue('=F2+1');
      let nDate = x.getRange('D2').getValue();
      let values = [ [ nDate, null ],[ "Left", "Returned" ] ];     
      x.getRange('D2:E3').setValues(values);
      let rng = x.getRange('D2:E184');
      rng.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK );
      rng.setBorder(null, null, null, null, null, true, '#818181', null );
      rng.setBorder(null, null, null, null, true, null, '#d8d4d4', null );

      for ( let j = 3; j < 184; j+=5 ) {
        
        let r = "D" + [j] + ":E" + [j];
        x.getRange(r).setBorder( null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK );

      }

    }  

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have worked :)

Comment: @LaurenAndrews I fixed a typo in  `Example Script` where I forgot to return the starting index to zero: `let i = 0`.  Now corrected.